# How to uninstall a Docker Image

Tags: docker, ubuntu, nginx, docker-compose, dockerfile

I ran this command `docker-compose up -d` inside a directory called `hosting`.

How can I uninstall that image it created, so I can reinstall it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the image by using the command:

```
docker rmi <image-name>:<image-version>
```

To list all images you can use:

```
docker images
```

Comment: It says `No such container` for some reason. But when I run `docker images`, they have the exact container name there that I'm copy and pasting from

Comment: try adding the ":version" beside the name, like if you have mysql image version 8.0 write the command like: docker rm mysql:8.0 or if you don't know the version try writing latest in place of the version like: docker rm mysql:latest

Answer (score 0):

You can simply again go to the `hosting` directory and run this:

```
docker-compose down
```

Or via `-f` argument specify the `docker-compose` file path:

```
docker-compose -f /path_to/hosting/docker-compose.yml down
```

When you use this, it stops the created containers and removes them.

Also if you want to update it, just do your work in your project (update the codes, the files and so on), then run this command to build the container:

```
docker-compose up -d --build
```